# Raspberry pi capturing rs232 data and outputting through pushover

Tags: python

I'm wondering if anyone would be able to help me? I can see loads of tutorials on using Python to capture data from RS-232 but I can't figure out how I would be able to use that data to send notifications every time data is captured through an API like pushover.

Any help would be massively appreciated - I'm a noob when it comes to this stuff.

Comment: There is no such thing as "RS-232 data". RS-232 defines the electrical characteristics and timing of signals, the meaning of signals, and the physical size and pinout of connectors. Try using pySerial to capture serial data.